# How to find the sum of two colums with a quantity value

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Ok so I am a lil confused how to go about this and seek some help..

I have a mysql db that has a column named quantity and another called price_paid

what I want to do is take and add up the entire column of price_paid but to also take into account a quantity higher than 1.

Ex..

```
_____________     ______________   
|  quantity  |   | price_paid  | 
--------------   ---------------
       1              2.99 
       2              9.99
       1              1.99
```

How would I create the php / mysql to make that = a total of 24.96 ?

So far I am able to get the total of price_paid but what I have doesn't take into account the quantity column and it's value.

```
$comic_totals = "SELECT sum(price_paid) AS value_sum FROM `comic_db`.`comic_db`";
$total_db = mysqli_query($comic_connect, $comic_totals);
if(!total_db){
        echo "Failed";
}
$tot_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_db);
$sum = $tot_array['value_sum'];
echo "$".$sum;
```

so how do I turn that into what I need? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let MySQL take care of multiplying the price by the quantity...

```
SELECT SUM(quantity * price_paid) AS value_sum
```

Comment: Sweet that worked perfectly for some reason I was thinking I was going to have to do something a lot more involved than that on the php side. TY Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want quantity higher than 1 then add where clause

Like this

```
SELCET SUM(quantity * price_paid) as value
FROM comic_db.comic_db
WHERE quantity > 1;
```

Comment: this will give wrong answer.. cause it will ignore the value for quantity 1 which should be part of the total sum for the item..

Comment: Yes, but he mention in his question that quantity is higher than 1.

Comment: he means that he wants product of both column where quantity is higher than one.. so if quantity is 2 and amount $2 it should give $4.. so if quantity 1 and value $2 .. it wont matter if he removes product.. its simple accounting problem.. also stated what result he wants.. so your query will grab 19.98 ignoring the other 2 values..